# why no such flag 'loggc' using jinfo

Tags: java, jvm

I want to know -Xloggc value for a given Java process with command

jinfo -flag loggc 12345，

but it prints: no such flag 'loggc'.

The explanation(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html) of command 'jinfo -flag name' is:

*prints the name and value of the given command line flag.*

so, is -Xloggc not command line flag?

Comment: This is a dump of all the flags `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version`  You might need to dump the command line args instead.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html is not quite accurate. In recent JDK (i.e. JDK 8u191 and JDK 11.0.1) it has been changed to

```
-flag <name>         to print the value of the named VM flag
```

`-Xloggc` is not a named JVM flag, but rather a command-line argument that is translated to multiple JVM flags, in particular, `-XX:+PrintGC` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`.

To get the VM command line, run

```
jcmd 12345 VM.command_line
```

To see the full list of JVM flags, run

```
jcmd 12345 VM.flags -all
```